# Why does the cd command occasionally take several seconds to complete?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, performance

Sometimes, when using the command prompt, the `cd` command finishes quickly, but often it takes several seconds. What does it indicate? What's the bottleneck?

Comment: Is the location you're trying to `cd` to a network resource, perhaps? Or maybe a hard drive that needs to spin up first? What happens when you try to open that location in Windows Explorer?

Comment: it's a hard drive. that location does open, but slowly.

Comment: A couple of things to try: 1) defrag the hard drive; 2) check [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) attributes with [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com) or similar utility; 3) run [`chkdsk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK) and see if it reports any errors.

Comment: how do i find the spinning speed of the hard disk?

Comment: HD Tune or Device Manager can give you the model number. Type that into your search engine of choice and you should find the specs, including the rotational speed.

Comment: `IDE\DiskHITACHI_HTS722010K9SA00_________________DC2ZC75A`. Google is not very helpful

Comment: Here, [let me Bing that for you](http://letmebingthatforyou.com/?q=hitachi%20HTS722010K9SA00). That's a Hitachi Travelstar 7K200, 100 GB, 7200 rpm, 16 MB cache.

Comment: @Indrek: thanks for the tip. `chkdsk`  really did work. It removed a lot of bad sectors and my lappy is fast again. :)

Comment: Good to hear :) I've posted my comment as an answer; consider accepting it so others who find this question can immediately see what fixed the problem for you. Also, keep running `chkdsk` regularly to see if the drive deteriorates further. If it does, back up your data and buy a new one as soon as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to try:

1. Defragment the hard drive. The built-in defrag utility is fine, though for more advanced tuning (system file defragmentation, free space consolidation etc.) you can look into third-party programs like [Auslogics Disk Defrag](http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/disk-defrag).
2. Check the hard drive's [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) attributes with [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com) or similar program. See the Wikipedia article for a list of attributes, including those that are potential indicators of hardware problems.
3. Run [`chkdsk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK) to find and fix errors with the filesystem and bad sectors on the hard drive.